# Check if "Continued" or "New" page

Tags: c#, itext

I would like to know if there is a way to check if the "New Page" happened because of exceeded table or programmatically (by using `doc.NewPage();`)?

If the new page caused because of exceeded table or text, I need to hide the header table and show a text instead, else if the new page caused programmatically I need to display the header table normally.

I tried to find a flag or something like this in the "OnStartPage" event that show me if the page exceeded or not, but I found nothing.

I hope that some one can help me here.

Thanks!

Comment: How about checking if the `y-coordinate` has reached in your set limit say `10` then you will start a new page?

Comment: First, thanks for the quick answer.
I can try this, but i have 2 questions. 
1. How can I read the Y coordinate of the current page?
2. Lets say that I know the Y coordinate, How can I edit the header if so?

Comment: You start from top right? Like in my case I start at `715` (for Portrait) and every line I add, I deducted say `25` until I reach a set limit say `35` and if it is reached I did a `doc.NewPage();`.

Comment: From where did you take the numbers 715, 25,35?

Comment: Those are arbitrary numbers.

Comment: I need more common and stable way to do it, not an arbitrary way, I have a lot of pdf reports and they gonna grow more at a time, so if I need to check every line this is not good enough for me.
I use it just if this is the only way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at the [`IPdfPTableEventSplit`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/IPdfPTableEventSplit.cs) interface that you can implement and assign to a [`PdfPTable.TableEvent`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPTable.cs#l1485) property. It has two methods, `SplitTable` and `TableLayout`. The first method is called whenever a table split happens, the second is called whenever the table actually gets written to the canvas. In the first method you could set a flag and disable the header rows if a split happened and in the second method you could write your content out.

The `SplitTable` method is fired *before* the new page is added so you need to keep track of a trinary state, "no split", "draw on next page" and "draw on this page". I've packaged these up as an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum SplitState {
    None = 0,
    DrawOnNextPage = 1,
    DrawOnThisPage = 2
}
```

The implemented interface would look like this:

```
public class SplitTableWatcher : IPdfPTableEventSplit {
    /// <summary>
    /// The current table split state
    /// </summary>
    private SplitState currentSplitState = SplitState.None;

    public void SplitTable(PdfPTable table) {
        //Disable header rows for automatic splitting (per OP's request)
        table.HeaderRows = 0;

        //We now need to split on the next page, so append the flag
        this.currentSplitState |= SplitState.DrawOnNextPage;
    }

    public void TableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        //If a split happened and we're on the next page
        if (this.currentSplitState.HasFlag(SplitState.DrawOnThisPage)) {

            //Draw something, nothing too special here
            var cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false), 18);

            //Use the table's widths and heights to find a spot, this probably could use some tweaking
            cb.SetTextMatrix(widths[0][0], heights[0]);
            cb.ShowText("A Split Happened!");
            cb.EndText();

            //Unset the draw on this page flag, it will be reset below if needed
            this.currentSplitState ^= SplitState.DrawOnThisPage;
        }

        //If we previously had the next page flag set change it to this page
        if (currentSplitState.HasFlag(SplitState.DrawOnNextPage)) {
            this.currentSplitState = SplitState.DrawOnThisPage;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the actual implementation of that class with some simple test data:

```
var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            var t = new PdfPTable(1);

            //Implement our class
            t.TableEvent = new SplitTableWatcher();

            //Add a single header row
            t.HeaderRows = 1;
            t.AddCell("Header");

            //Create 100 test cells
            for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                t.AddCell(i.ToString());
            }
            doc.Add(t);

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```