# How to get last written data location in a PDF page during PDF creation using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I am adding hundreds of tables one after the other to the PDF document using iTextSharp. But the problem with this is we don't know when to create new page. And  sometimes half of the table goes to the next page and half remain in the current page.Is there any way I can have last written location so that I can decide whether to create new page or not.

I found some codes on StackOverFlow but none worked for me.
I tried to get location using below code before adding new data to the document.

```
float y = PdfPageHeight; 
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    if(y<=document.document.BottomMargin)
    {
      document.NewPage();
    }
    mainTableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);
    mainTableHeader.SetWidthPercentage(new float[] { PageSize.A4.Width }, PageSize.A4);
    AddContent(ref mainTableHeader); //Adding some cells to the table
    document.Add(mainTableHeader);
    y=writer.GetVerticalPosition(false);
}
```

Please help me if any one knows how to do this.

Comment: I don't know if it will help but the `PdfPTable` has a property called `TableEvent` that you can subscribe to by creating a class that implements the interface `IPdfPTableEvent` and there's actually a more informative interface called `IPdfPTableEventSplit` that's dedicated to table splitting. You can see an example of its [usage here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24996393/231316). You might be able to use this to keep track of things with a global object.

Comment: `y<=document.document.RightMargin` - why do you compare a **y** value with the *right* margin. That doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: @mkl - Hey its " y<=document.BottomMargin ". Tried this code only but every time  I calculate the "y" value it remains constant.

Comment: When do you do that test? `writer.GetVerticalPosition` only changes when something is added to the document, not while you still construct a table to add.

Comment: @mkl - every time I add a new table to document I use to do that test. And every time I am getting same value.

Comment: Are you adding your table to the document using `document.Add()` or are you using something like a `ColumnText` or `WriteSelectedRows()`?

Comment: @Jakob you had really better add some code to your question. As Chris and I hint at in our comments, that `GetVerticalPosition` only returns meaningful data if you let itext do the layout, i.e. if you use the `Document` method `Add`. If you do, please supply some code to reproduce the issue. If you don't, the **y** coordinate is under your control anyways.

Comment: @mkl - Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong in the below code   float y = PdfPageHeight; //initializing pdf height with already manipulated value
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
 if(y<=document.document.BottomMargin)
 {
   document.NewPage();
 }
 mainTableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);
 mainTableHeader.SetWidthPercentage(new float[] { PageSize.A4.Width }, PageSize.A4);
 AddContent(ref mainTableHeader); //Adding some cells to the table
 document.Add(mainTableHeader);
 y=writer.GetVerticalPosition(false);
}`

Answer (score 1):

I took your code with minor changes (replaced your unknown method `AddContent` with code actually *adding some cells to the table*; added some `Console` outputs):

```
using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
    document.Open();

    float y = document.PageSize.Height;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (y <= document.BottomMargin)
        {
            Console.Write("New Page!\n");
            document.NewPage();
        }
        PdfPTable mainTableHeader = new PdfPTable(1);
        mainTableHeader.SetWidthPercentage(new float[] { PageSize.A4.Width }, PageSize.A4);
        mainTableHeader.AddCell("Test");
        mainTableHeader.AddCell(writer.GetVerticalPosition(false).ToString());
        mainTableHeader.AddCell(writer.GetVerticalPosition(false).ToString());
        document.Add(mainTableHeader);
        y = writer.GetVerticalPosition(false);
        Console.Write("After table {0} y is at {1}\n", i, y);
    } 
}
```

Running this code I see on the console:

```
After table 0 y is at 758
After table 1 y is at 710
After table 2 y is at 662
After table 3 y is at 614
After table 4 y is at 566
After table 5 y is at 518
After table 6 y is at 470
After table 7 y is at 422
After table 8 y is at 374
After table 9 y is at 326
After table 10 y is at 278
After table 11 y is at 230
After table 12 y is at 182
After table 13 y is at 134
After table 14 y is at 86
After table 15 y is at 38
After table 16 y is at 758
After table 17 y is at 710
After table 18 y is at 662
After table 19 y is at 614
After table 20 y is at 566
After table 21 y is at 518
After table 22 y is at 470
After table 23 y is at 422
After table 24 y is at 374
After table 25 y is at 326
After table 26 y is at 278
After table 27 y is at 230
After table 28 y is at 182
After table 29 y is at 134
After table 30 y is at 86
After table 31 y is at 38
After table 32 y is at 758
After table 33 y is at 710
After table 34 y is at 662
After table 35 y is at 614
After table 36 y is at 566
After table 37 y is at 518
After table 38 y is at 470
After table 39 y is at 422
After table 40 y is at 374
After table 41 y is at 326
After table 42 y is at 278
After table 43 y is at 230
After table 44 y is at 182
After table 45 y is at 134
After table 46 y is at 86
After table 47 y is at 38
After table 48 y is at 758
After table 49 y is at 710
After table 50 y is at 662
After table 51 y is at 614
After table 52 y is at 566
After table 53 y is at 518
After table 54 y is at 470
After table 55 y is at 422
After table 56 y is at 374
After table 57 y is at 326
After table 58 y is at 278
After table 59 y is at 230
After table 60 y is at 182
After table 61 y is at 134
After table 62 y is at 86
After table 63 y is at 38
After table 64 y is at 758
After table 65 y is at 710
After table 66 y is at 662
After table 67 y is at 614
After table 68 y is at 566
After table 69 y is at 518
After table 70 y is at 470
After table 71 y is at 422
After table 72 y is at 374
After table 73 y is at 326
After table 74 y is at 278
After table 75 y is at 230
After table 76 y is at 182
After table 77 y is at 134
After table 78 y is at 86
After table 79 y is at 38
After table 80 y is at 758
After table 81 y is at 710
After table 82 y is at 662
After table 83 y is at 614
After table 84 y is at 566
After table 85 y is at 518
After table 86 y is at 470
After table 87 y is at 422
After table 88 y is at 374
After table 89 y is at 326
After table 90 y is at 278
After table 91 y is at 230
After table 92 y is at 182
After table 93 y is at 134
After table 94 y is at 86
After table 95 y is at 38
After table 96 y is at 758
After table 97 y is at 710
After table 98 y is at 662
After table 99 y is at 614
```

Thus, your claims in comments that

> every time I calculate the "y" value it remains constant

or

> every time I add a new table to document I use to do that test. And every time I am getting same value.

cannot be reproduced with your code: **y** obviously is wildly changing all the time.

Thus, if you want help, please do provide sample code that allows people to reproduce your problem, not to disprove your claims.